# Problem with a tutorial about firebase+react

Tags: reactjs, firebase

i'm currently trying to learn Firebase and React, for a single-page-application which reads data from a Realtime Database hosted on Firebase.

I'm on a tutorial from Google/Firebase themself, where they are explaining how to get started with Firebase and React together. ([Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4XTMvagQ2Q))

My code from the create-react-app differs from the code shown in the video, and even if i alter the code to the code shown in the video it doesn't work.

Code before altering:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

function App() {

  constructor(
    super(),
    this.state = {
      speed: 10
    }
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{this.state.speed}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Code after altering:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

class App extend Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      speed: 10
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>{this.state.speed}</h1>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Code before altering gives me this compiling error:

```
./src/App.js
  Line 8:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

   6 | function App() {
   7 | 
>  8 |   constructor() {
     |                 ^
   9 |     super();
  10 |     this.state = {
  11 |       speed: 10
```

Altered Code gives me this compiling error:

```
./src/App.js
  Line 6:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "{"

  4 | import * as firebase from 'firebase';
  5 | 
> 6 | class App extend Component {
    |           ^
  7 |   constructor() {
  8 |     super();
  9 |     this.state = {
```

Any help is really appreciated, i'm completely new to Firebase and React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must write `extends` instead `extend`:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      speed: 10
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>{this.state.speed}</h1>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```